# JSON format to Data Frame in Python

Tags: python, json, database, dataframe

I am reading API data from the cloud server in JSON format as shown here

[image]

How to write a code to store this data frame into the data frame in any database. How to convert JSON format to DataFrame?

The requirement output format is shown in table[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSYuY.png)

Comment: kindly share your required output format

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
from requests import request
import json
import pandas as pd
response = request(url="http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json", method='get')# API source
data=json.loads(response.text)['people']# pick the 'people' data source from json
pd.DataFrame(data) # convert to pandas dataframe
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: How can you convert json nested to nested object representation to pandas Dataframe object.  which is present in asked question.

Comment: this link will surely help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455945/convert-json-with-nested-objects-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: also consider using this `pandas.io.json.json_normalize` is your json is nested

Comment: I think if you can paste a sample of your json output we can help you with the way to restructure it into a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0):

check out the [docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("http://some.com/blah.json")
```

and as for storing it to a database you will need to know some things about your database connection.  [docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html?highlight=to_sql#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql)

```
tablename = "my_tablename"
connection_values = <your sql alchemy connection here>
df.to_sql(name=tablename, con=connection_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, tell me if it works!

```
import request
import json
import pandas as pd

response = request(url='http://google.com') # Assuming the url
res = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Goodluck mate!

Answer (score 0):

To help others also, here is an example with nested json. I have tried to make this similar to the example you showed in your question.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.json as pd_json
jsondata = '''
{
    "source": { "id": "2480300" },
    "time": "2013-07-02T16:32:30.152+02:00",
    "type": "huawei_E3131SignalStrength",
    "c8y_SignalStrength": {
        "rssi": { "value": -53, "unit": "dBm" },
        "ber": { "value": 0.14, "unit": "%" } 
    }
}


'''

data = pd_json.loads(jsondata) #load 
df=pd_json.json_normalize(data) #normalise
df
```

Result:

```
   c8y_SignalStrength.ber.unit  c8y_SignalStrength.ber.value    c8y_SignalStrength.rssi.unit    c8y_SignalStrength.rssi.value   source.id   time    type
  % 0.14    dBm -53 2480300 2013-07-02T16:32:30.152+02:00   huawei_E3131SignalStrength
```